# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `address` limit 1)

Tags: php, docker, networking, etl

In Docker ,I Run my PHP Program (Container 1) which taking data from database (Container 2, Port:3311) >> SUCCESS if i run it locally || But when with Docker the connection refused || I already make connection by database.php and docker Bridge called 'Laravel' but still. What else should i do? Here the error notification :
[image]

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `address` limit 1)

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
  755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
  756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
  757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
  758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
  760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
  761▕             );
  762▕         }
  763▕     }

    +20 vendor frames
  21  app/Console/Commands/showAddress.php:32
    Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::get()

    +13 vendor frames
  35  artisan:37
    Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

database.php :

```
'sakiladb' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '3311',
        'database' => 'sakila',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'rootpass',
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Docker Network (i use 'laravel' to bridge) :
[image]

PHP Docker File :

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.0.2-fpm-alpine3.7
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION:+${PHP_VERSION}-}fpm-alpine

RUN apk update; \
   apk upgrade;

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

Apache Docker File :

```
FROM httpd:2.4.33-alpine
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;
# Copy apache vhost file to proxy php requests to php-fpm container
COPY demo.apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

demo.apache.conf :

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module 
/usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ 
fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

Docker-compese.yml :

```
version: "3.2"
networks:
  laravel:
    external:
      name: laravel
services:
  php:
    build: 
      context: './php/'
      args:
       PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
    networks:
      - laravel
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
    container_name: php
  apache:
    build:
      context: './apache/'
      args:
       APACHE_VERSION: ${APACHE_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
    container_name: apache

volumes:
  data:
```

Comment: What is DATABASE_URL?

Comment: Shouldn't `host` be `mariadbtest`, because you what to connect the database container not connect to a service inside the  `php` container?

Comment: BTW: Shore error messages and other details as text not as image.

Comment: @Jens may u check, Sir. I add it

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using wrong DB configuration. Use DB configuration from the DB container.

**Host: mariadbtest**

**port:3306**

On the other hand, add mysql to your docker-compose under container name
**mariadbtest**. Then again under `depends_on:` you must add `mariadbtest` as well

Add below to php Dockerfile

```
RUN php artisan view:clear
RUN php artisan route:clear
RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: `port 3311` is exposed not `3306`

Comment: Here you have to add the internal port 3306

Comment: No. You connect from outside the container, so you have to use the exposed port

Comment: He has a network configured between containers

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi i try with (3311) , (3311:3306), (3306) are the same, Sir.

Comment: @RonaldoFirmansyah now working or not ?

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi not yet, Sir. I try some method in internet. Found not as same as my case but look alike and try it, still connection refused

Comment: Add cache clear commands  as well. I just updated the answer

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi executor failed running, Sir

Comment: Can you please share your Dockerfile?

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi Done, Sir. Check it please

Comment: Add docker-compose.yml also please

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi Oh, sorry, Sir. Done

Comment: MySQL is not  included in your docker-compose. Why is that?

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi actually, i was trying 2 ways. FIRST WAY is put the database in mysql ( 1 container with php and Apache ). SECOND WAY is no need mysql, just put the database in 'mariadbtest' instead. the result was both has the same error.

Comment: Try the way I mentioned in the answer. Add mysql into the docker-compose. Let me give you a link where you can guide  https://shouts.dev/articles/dockerize-a-laravel-app-with-apache-mariadb

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi It work with some adjustment, Sir. Many thank you. Addtionally question, can we add another database connection with diffrent port in it? because i try to define connection in database.php and .env still not detected

Comment: Yes all the time external port must be different. Internal you can repeat with 3306 and remember, use a different name for the container. Please if above answer help you to solve your problem, mask sure to mark as useful answer. Thanks

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi Done, Sir. Thank you. I just confused because its different port (8123) and it wont connect